# Why am I getting a http status code of 200 instead of 302

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm checking a list of sites to see if they redirect but I'm getting a HTTP code 200 for sites that I know have a 302 code. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import urllib2

with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    sites = f.readlines()

for url in sites:
    try:
        connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        print connection.getcode()
        connection.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.getcode()
```

Comment: Thank you so much poke! I googled left and right and couldn't come up with an answer.

Comment: Yeah, it is a pretty well hidden feature of urllib. You’re welcome :)

Comment: How would I go about finding how to make it faster now?

Comment: You could use multiprocessing or multithreading to make multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: Thanks once again :)